# How to set orientation to LTR in MediaWiki app

Tags: php, localization, mediawiki

*How to change text orientation to LTR in MediaWiki app*? After setting language using method `setCode('en')` displaying language change from AR to EN, but orientation is not changed.

Comment: Where do you call `setCode`? In a skin? An extension? A bit of context would help here!

Comment: I call `setCode` in a skin, language changed but orientation not.

Comment: You need to provide the relevant parts of yuor code, otherwise we can only guess, but remember that directionality is CSS driven in MediaWiki, by setting a class to the html element. If you use `headelement` in your skin code, then you will need to change the language _before_ `$wgOut::headElement()` is called. If you are printing out the html element manually, just add `class=ltr` to it.

Comment: `public function execute()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] === 'en'){
            $this->getSkin()->getContext()->setLanguage('en');
        };

        $this->html('headelement');`

Comment: is `lang` supposed to change the page language? Or the interface language? How is it different from the built in `uselang`?

Comment: On my custom page, I put a link with param lang=en (for example). I didn't find in manual about `uselang`.

Comment: To change the interface language, use `uselang=en`, etc. If you are buidling a custom skin with more advanced language handling, you might want to start by reading up on https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Language

Comment: Thanks. `uselang=en` help me to solve my issue. Can you copy your comment to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the interface language, use

> `uselang=en`

, etc. If you are building a custom skin with more advanced language handling, you might want to start by reading up on mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Language. Thank's Leo